# Creating an empty structure

Tags: c

I've got a structure of this type :

```
#define SUDOKU_SIZE 9
typedef struct {
   int grid[SUDOKU_SIZE][SUDOKU_SIZE];
} sudoku_t;
```

But when I want to create one : `struct sudoku_t sudo;`

I got this error : error: storage size of ‘s’ isn’t known

Thanks

Comment: I see no `s`.Where is it?

Comment: There's no such type as `struct sudoku_t` in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `typedef`, you create a new type; you can simply reference it by its name `sudoku_t` (instead of `struct sudoku_t`). So instead of `struct sudoku_t s;` write

```
sudoku_t s;
```

If for some reason you actually *want* to create a named struct, drop the typedef:

```
struct sudoku_t {
   int grid[SUDOKU_SIZE][SUDOKU_SIZE];
};

int main() {
    struct sudoku_t s;
}
```

Comment: Good point, OP, if you want to use both (with or without `struct` keyword) use `typedef struct sudoku_t {int grid[SUDOKU_SIZE][SUDOKU_SIZE];} sudoku_t;`

Comment: What's so strange about creating a named struct? Some of us prefer to use struct tags and drop the typedefs.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah, you're right. I've removed the prejudiced wording in this answer.